# RewriteRule to Replace Substring in URL

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My problem sounds very simple, however I can’t figure it out and after I looked everywhere as much as could, I didn't find anything.

I have multiple pages that have the following name format:

```
www.mydomain.com/cat1/name-prefix-***hello-world***-name-suffix.html
```

I need to create a rule that would output the following name format:

```
www.mydomain.com/cat1/name-prefix-***new-static-string***-name-suffix.html
```

I guess, since I have multiple pages I have to use regular expression that would match the substring ***`hello-world`*** and replace it with ***`new-static-string`*** but I am not sure if this can be achieved with `mod_rewrite` or if I should take a different approach.

Also my pages are not exclusively in the directory `/cat1`. They can be in `/cat2`, `/cat3` or `/whatever_cat` and also they can be in the root or at a fifth level sub-directory.

In other words the rule will have to target the file name only regardless the file path.

Comment: Have a look to apache mod_rewrite docs and tell us what you tried. (Hint : yes you can use regex)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rule is as simple as:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)-hello-world-(.*)$ $1-new-static-string-$2 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: @CubikRube Select this reply as answer (green tick-mark). The question will not appear as unanswered.

Comment: Good one. If you don't mind could you please explain your string `^(.*)-hello-world-(.*)$ $1-new-static-string-$2 [R=301,L,NC]` in your answer, including what is `[R=301,L,NC]`.